# Query To Return Values Where NOT All Text

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql

I have a field that is `varchar(100)` - if the field is all text, I want to ignore it, if it is alpha-numeric I want to return the data.  This is sample DDL and my `ISNUMERIC()` excludes both values (I assume because they contain text with the numbers).

How should this be altered in order to return any value that is not just text?

```
Declare @Table Table (field1 varchar(100))
Insert Into @Table Values 
('1ZCLJKSDFLKSJDF'), 
('0301190XFS3'), 
('Pink Socks Run Free'), 
('White Goats Stink')

Select * from @table where ISNUMERIC(field1) >= 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fairly simple:

```
Select * from @table where field1 LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```